# How to pass xcrun environment variables to Calabash launcher?

Tags: ios, xcode, calabash, calabash-ios

I am running calabash-ios using calabash-cucumber version 0.11.3, run_loop version 1.0.9.

As part of debugging our app we put an environment variable in to be used at runtime. I have been using xcrun about like this to launch the app:

```
xcrun instruments -t "Automation" -w "iPad Retina (8.1 Simulator)" myApp.app -e"myEnvVar=YES"
```

Or I would put this in the list of scheme environment variables when using the xcode GUI.

How do I set the environment variable (-e) when running with calabash?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported yet, but we hope it will be soon.